# How to change ReportServerUrl in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reporting-services, reports, report-builder

We have 2 reporting server. One for test and one for production. Our business analyst will build the reports (rdl files) using Report Builder 3.0. After they complete the development and test on test reporting server (e.g. http://test/reportserver), we will modify the "ReportServerUrl" and Datasource, and then upload to production reporting server (e.g. http://prod/reportserver).

The problem is I cannot find in the Report Builder 3.0 UI how to configure this change. The only way I find is open the RDL file using Notepad, locate `<rd:ReportServerUrl>` and then change the URL.

Since our analyst are not programmers I want to avoid use notepad. May I know where is the button to change ReportServerUrl?